# How to add a button to hide and show a table, I can hide the table but it does not show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a button to toggle (show/hide) a table. My code will hide the table, but it will not show again. Once I click the button, the table disappears. But when I click it again it looks like it does a weird refresh or redirect. I am assuming the file is lost and the table will not show again. Here is my code:

```js
class TableCsv {
  /**
   * @param {HTMLTableElement} root The table element which will display the CSV data.
   */
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  /**
   * Clears existing data in the table and replaces it with new data.
   *
   * @param {string[][]} data A 2D array of data to be used as the table body
   * @param {string[]} headerColumns List of headings to be used
   */
  update(data, headerColumns = []) {
    this.clear();
    this.setHeader(headerColumns);
    this.setBody(data);
  }

  /**
   * Clears all contents of the table (incl. the header).
   */
  clear() {
    this.root.innerHTML = "";
  }

  /**
   * Sets the table header.
   *
   * @param {string[]} headerColumns List of headings to be used
   */

  setHeader(headerColumns) {
    this.root.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      `
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        ${headerColumns.map((text) => `<th>${text}</th>`).join("")}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            `
    );
  }

  /**
   * Sets the table body.
   *
   * @param {string[][]} data A 2D array of data to be used as the table body
   */

  setBody(data) {
    const rowsHtml = data.map((row) => {
      return `
                    <tr>
                        ${row.map((text) => `<td>${text}</td>`).join("")}
                    </tr>
                `;
    });

    this.root.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `
                <tbody>
                    ${rowsHtml.join("")}
                </tbody>
            `
    );
  }
}

const tableRoot = document.querySelector("#csvRoot");
const csvFileInput = document.querySelector("#csvFileInput");
const tableCsv = new TableCsv(tableRoot);

csvFileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  Papa.parse(csvFileInput.files[0], {
    delimiter: ",",
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    complete: (results) => {
      tableCsv.update(results.data.slice(1), results.data[0]);
    }
  });
});

function hidefunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById('csvRoot');
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.display = "visible";
  }
  x.style.display = "hidden";
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

th {
  background: #fd264f;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #191828;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>EasyBudget</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href={{ url_for( 'static', filename='easybudgetcss.css' ) }}>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.2/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-SGWgwwRA8xZgEoKiex3UubkSkV1zSE1BS6O4pXcaxcNtUlQsOmOmhVnDwIvqGRfEmuz83tIGL13cXMZn6upPyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight">

    <div class="hero-head">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-end">
              <div id="easyb">
                <a href=#>EasyBudget</a>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">My Account</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href=#>Profile</a>
                  <a href=#>My List</a>
                  <a href=#>Logout</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <h1 style="text-align: center">
    Budgeting made easy
  </h1>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-2">
      <label for="tab2-1">Budget Tool</label>
      <input id="tab2-1" name="tabs-two" type="radio" checked="checked">
      <div>
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Let's Get Started</h2>
        <form action="/">
          <div class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            <label for="csvFileInput" style="text-align: left">Select a file:</label>
            <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" style="cursor: pointer; padding-bottom: 30px">
            <table id="csvRoot"></table>
            <button type="submit" onclick="hidefunction()">Hide table</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-2">
      <label for="tab2-2">Best Practices</label>
      <input id="tab2-2" name="tabs-two" type="radio">
      <div>
        <h4>Some Advice for Later</h4>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='netlfixclonejs.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.2.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm thinking the answer may be a sessionStorage or something. sorry im trying to self learn coding

Comment: The proper values of `.style.display` are `none` and `block`. `visible` and `hidden` are for `.style.visibility`. You're testing visibility in the `if`, but then setting display.

Comment: And the code to hide it should be in an `else` block. Your code hides it even after it makes it visible.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar mentioned, the proper values are as follows:

`style.display` takes `none` or `block`

`style.visibility` takes `hidden` or `visible`

Again as @Barmar mentioned, I corrected the structure of the `if..else` blocks to hide and show the table as you required.

I added a `removeFunction()` to show the difference between removing an element and hiding it. If you set `style.display:none` then the element is removed from the page and the contents move to fill the gap. However, if you set `style.visibility:hidden`, the element remains in the same position, nothing moves, but the element is no longer visible.

Because the button was a `submit` button, the page was being refreshed in a weird way as you describe. So, I also changed the type of the button from `submit` to `button`.

Here is a minimal code demo:

```js
function hidefunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById('csvRoot');
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function removefunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById('csvRoot');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table id="csvRoot">
  <thead>
    <th>2010</th><th>2011</th><th>2012</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>112</td><td>321</td><td>411</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>131</td><td>133</td><td>331</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>331</td><td>133</td><td>131</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="hidefunction()">Hide/Show table</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removefunction()">Remove/Replace table</button>
```